# Почему приложение .py выглядит на разных компьютерах по разному?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Есть приложение, показывающее погоду на всю неделю, однако у меня на компьютере оно выглядит не так, как на компьютере другого человека, от чего это зависит и как сделать так чтобы везде оно выглядело одинаково?

Вот как оно выглядит у меня

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как оно выглядит на компьюете другого человека

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В первом окне просто больше шрифт => скорее всего, в системных настройках операционки Вашего компьютера установлено увеличение шрифта для программ (например, 125%).

Comment: А можно сделать так, чтобы шрифт приложения подстраивался под шрифт в windows?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, Вам надо чтобы не шрифт подстраивался (он как раз и подстраивается), а чтобы приложение подстраивало свой размер, чтобы все надписи оставались читабельными. Либо нужно насильно задавать свои размеры шрифтов вне зависимости от настроек системы, но это будет не очень хорошо...

Comment: Понял, спасибо за помощь